# Visio Formula Units

Tags: visio, shapes, units-of-measurement

Could anyone be so kind to provide the full table of all possible units and they acronyms for Visio shape values (like Width, Height, etc.)
I know that default units are inches, also know how to specify millimeters (mm), like that "".
I guess there are other kind of units. I tried to find this info on msdn, but failed. If anyone can provide this info, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully nobody says "let me google that for you" here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767977.aspx